# how to create a class in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm a newbie in jQuery. I want to create a class in which one variable will be string and another will be an array. for this i am using this code.

```
var Animal = Class.create({
  init: function(name, sound) {
    this.name = name;
    this.sound = sound;
  }

});
var arr= new Array();
arr.push['kitty'];
arr.push['mitty'];
var cat = new Animal(arr,'meow' );
jsonString = JSON.stringify(cat);
alert(jsonString);
```

but i'm geeting my array value empty in alert. can anybody please guide me

Comment: jQuery doesn't have classes, and what is `Class` supposed to be in that code ?

Comment: i want to create an object in which one will be array variable and another will be a simple variable. and want to pass it through ajax call

Comment: `Class.create` sound like prototype.js-Style: http://api.prototypejs.org/language/Class/create/

Answer (score 3):

In `JavaScript` there are no classes. You could mimic the way we create objects in C# or JAVA for instance like below:

```
function Animal(name, sound)
{
    this.name = name;
    this.sound = sound;
}

var animal = new Animal("name","sound");
```

This is called the *constructor pattern*. Notice that by convention the name of the `function` that **mimics** the concept of a class declaration starts with a capital letter.

**Update**

I am talking about ES5. The next version of JavaScript will contain a concept similar to classes. [@silviu-burcea](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1051677/silviu-burcea) thanks for your comment.

> is there any way to create an object whose parameter will an array and
>   a string variable. and pass it through ajax call

Yes it is possible. For instance,

```
// The constructor for a Zoo.
function Zoo(animals, name)
{
    this.animals = animals;
    this.name = name;
}

// Let's create a Zoo
var zoo = new Zoo(["Dog","Cat","Fish","Bird"], "Welcome to the Jungle");
```

Then you could pass this object, `zoo`, the same way you would do with any other object in a ajax call.

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'your url',
    method: ...,
    cache: ...,
    data: zoo,
    success: function(){
        // the statements that would be executed 
        // if the ajax call be successful.
    }
});
```

Comment: is there any way to create an object whose parameter will an array and a string variable. and pass it through ajax call

Comment: ES6 standard has classes: http://javascriptplayground.com/blog/2014/07/introduction-to-es6-classes-tutorial/

Comment: Javascript has link-object delegation via prototype inheritance, and you can implement you classic class-based  inheritance over it. Or use ES6 classes